# How to retrieve data from a Mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I'm writing an app in the MEAN stack using mongoose as my ORM.

I am implementing the Create and Read operations in the CRUD process.

My page schema is as follows

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var pageSchema = new moongose.Schema({
pageExtension:{
    type:String,
    default:"html"
},
publicFileRoot:{
    type:String,
    default:"/dist/"
},
testAttribute:{
    type:String
},
title:{
    type:String,
    required:[true ,'title is required']
},
pageName:{
    type:String,
    required:[true, "the page name for this page is required"]
},
routeUri:{
    type:String
},
projects:[{
    type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:projectSchema
}],
fileUrl:{
    type:String,
    required:[true, "the file url is requred"],
    default:this.publicFileRoot + this.pageName
},
pageID:{
    type:Number,
    index:true,
    unique:true,
    required:true
},
webUrl:{
    type:String
},
lastUpdated:{type:Date, default:Date.now, required:[true, 'the last updated Date is required']},
_mongoID: {type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, description:"mongoDB's Unique ID"},
staticFiles:{
    css:{
        type:Array,
        url:{
            type:String
        }
    },
    js:[{
        type:Array,
        url:{
            type:String
        }
    }],
    html:[{
        url:{
            type:String
        }
    }],
    img:[{
        type:Array,
        imgID:{
            type:String
        },
        imgUrl:{

        }

    }]
}
});
module.exports = pageSchema;
```

My database script is as follows

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/test';
var conn = mongoose.createConnection(mongoDBConnectionURI,{useMongoClient:true})
.on('connected',function(){
    console.log("connected to database");
});
var pageModel = conn.model('PageModel',pageSchema);
var readCallback = function(err,doc){
  if(err){
      console.error.bind(console,err);
  }
  else{
    return doc.collections;
  }
}
var create = function(Model,options = {}{
var newDocument = new Model(options);
validationError = newDocument.validateSync();
 if(validationError){
    console.log("on create: validation error:" + validationError);
 }
 else{
    newDocument.save(function(err,newDocument){
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        else return newDocument;
    });
 }
}
 //this function should query the database and return the result of the query
var read = function(Model, options, callback){
//options should contain an object with the format {attribute:value}
//check if the Model variable is defined
if(Model===undefined){
// the model reference is required
    throw new Error("Error on db.read: Model is undefined");
}
//check if the attribute
else if(options.attribute === undefined){
    //if no attribute is specified then just return the result of a model.find operation
     return Model.find({attribute:value},readCallback);
}
else{
   //if value is undefined assume user wants to return all results limited to attribute only
   if(options[options.attribute] === undefined){

        return Model.find({})
            .exec(
                  function(err,doc){
                    if (err) console.error.bind(console,error);
                    else return doc;
            });
    }
    //model, attribute, value are defined. perform a specific search
    else{

            return Model.findOne(options,readcallback);
         }
    }
  }
}
```

Test of the create function:

```
create(pageModel,
 {
     pageName:"testpage 1",
     title:"testing the functioning of the database",
     pageID:4
 },
);
```

Here are the results of the create function as shown by MongoDB compass

[image: the create function worked]

Test of the read function:

`console.log(pageModel.find({"pageName":"testpage 1"},readCallback);`

Here is the result of a console.log on the function above

```
    Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  mongooseCollection:
   NativeCollection {
     collection: null,
     opts: { bufferCommands: true, capped: false },
     name: 'pagemodels',
     collectionName: 'pagemodels',
     conn:
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: null,
        port: null,
        user: null,
        pass: null,
        name: null,
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 2,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: false,
        _listening: false,
        _connectionOptions: {},
        then: [Function],
        catch: [Function],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     queue: [],
     buffer: true,
     emitter:
      EventEmitter {
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _eventsCount: 0,
        _maxListeners: undefined } },
  model:
   { [Function: model]
     hooks: Kareem { _pres: {}, _posts: {} },
     base:
      Mongoose {
        connections: [Array],
        models: {},
        modelSchemas: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        plugins: [Array] },
     modelName: 'PageModel',
     model: [Function: model],
     db:
      NativeConnection {
        base: [Object],
        collections: [Object],
        models: [Object],
        config: [Object],
        replica: false,
        hosts: null,
        host: null,
        port: null,
        user: null,
        pass: null,
        name: null,
        options: null,
        otherDbs: [],
        _readyState: 2,
        _closeCalled: false,
        _hasOpened: false,
        _listening: false,
        _connectionOptions: {},
        then: [Function],
        catch: [Function],
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     discriminators: undefined,
     '$appliedHooks': true,
     _events: { init: [Function], save: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     schema:
      Schema {
        obj: [Object],
        paths: [Object],
        aliases: {},
        subpaths: {},
        virtuals: [Object],
        singleNestedPaths: {},
        nested: [Object],
        inherits: {},
        callQueue: [Array],
        _indexes: [],
        methods: {},
        statics: {},
        tree: [Object],
        query: {},
        childSchemas: [Array],
        plugins: [Array],
        s: [Object],
        options: [Object],
        '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
     collection:
      NativeCollection {
        collection: null,
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'pagemodels',
        collectionName: 'pagemodels',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: true,
        emitter: [Object] },
     Query: { [Function] base: [Object] },
     '$__insertMany': [Function],
     insertMany: [Function] },
  schema:
   Schema {
     obj:
      { pageExtension: [Object],
        publicFileRoot: [Object],
        testAttribute: [Object],
        title: [Object],
        pageName: [Object],
        routeUri: [Object],
        projects: [Array],
        fileUrl: [Object],
        pageID: [Object],
        webUrl: [Object],
        lastUpdated: [Object],
        _mongoID: [Object],
        staticFiles: [Object] },
     paths:
      { pageExtension: [Object],
        publicFileRoot: [Object],
        testAttribute: [Object],
        title: [Object],
        pageName: [Object],
        routeUri: [Object],
        projects: [Object],
        fileUrl: [Object],
        pageID: [Object],
        webUrl: [Object],
        lastUpdated: [Object],
        _mongoID: [Object],
        'staticFiles.css': [Object],
        'staticFiles.js': [Object],
        'staticFiles.html': [Object],
        'staticFiles.img': [Object],
        _id: [Object],
        __v: [Object] },
     aliases: {},
     subpaths: {},
     virtuals: { id: [Object] },
     singleNestedPaths: {},
     nested: { staticFiles: true },
     inherits: {},
     callQueue: [ [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array], [Array] ],
     _indexes: [],
     methods: {},
     statics: {},
     tree:
      { pageExtension: [Object],
        publicFileRoot: [Object],
        testAttribute: [Object],
        title: [Object],
        pageName: [Object],
        routeUri: [Object],
        projects: [Array],
        fileUrl: [Object],
        pageID: [Object],
        webUrl: [Object],
        lastUpdated: [Object],
        _mongoID: [Object],
        staticFiles: [Object],
        _id: [Object],
        id: [Object],
        __v: [Function: Number] },
     query: {},
     childSchemas: [ [Object] ],
     plugins: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
     s: { hooks: [Object], kareemHooks: [Object] },
     options:
      { retainKeyOrder: false,
        typeKey: 'type',
        id: true,
        noVirtualId: false,
        _id: true,
        noId: false,
        validateBeforeSave: true,
        read: null,
        shardKey: null,
        autoIndex: null,
        minimize: true,
        discriminatorKey: '__t',
        versionKey: '__v',
        capped: false,
        bufferCommands: true,
        strict: true,
        pluralization: true },
     '$globalPluginsApplied': true },
  op: 'find',
  options: { retainKeyOrder: false },
  _conditions: {},
  _fields: undefined,
  _update: undefined,
  _path: undefined,
  _distinct: undefined,
  _collection:
   NodeCollection {
     collection:
      NativeCollection {
        collection: null,
        opts: [Object],
        name: 'pagemodels',
        collectionName: 'pagemodels',
        conn: [Object],
        queue: [],
        buffer: true,
        emitter: [Object] },
     collectionName: 'pagemodels' },
  _traceFunction: undefined,
  _count: [Function],
  _execUpdate: [Function],
  _find: [Function],
  _findOne: [Function],
  _findOneAndRemove: [Function],
  _findOneAndUpdate: [Function],
  _replaceOne: [Function],
  _updateMany: [Function],
  _updateOne: [Function] }
```

Just for extra help, here's my MongoDB log for today(was too big to fit here):
[mongodb.log](https://gist.github.com/jtmorris-gamedev/95997949d429e5d1d5de409192423ebd)

The final part of the question:

How do I do a make a find operation return the results of the create function as shown in the MongoDB compass picture? I've been racking my brain for three days trying to figure this out and don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any help or explanation of the processes involved would be very helpful.

Comment: I originally tried to connect to the database using the account Admin with a password, but it failed and i removed it right now

Answer (score 0):

```
 //this function should query the database and return the result of the     query
var read = function(Model, options, callback){
//options should contain an object with the format {attribute:value}
//check if the Model variable is defined
if(Model===undefined){
// the model reference is required
throw new Error("Error on db.read: Model is undefined");
}
//check if the attribute
else if(options.attribute === undefined){
    //if no attribute is specified then just return the result of a model.find operation
 return Model.find({attribute:value},readCallback);
}
```

With reference to the above read function definition your third parameter is callback and when you are returning the result you are not using callback.

Comment: do you mind giving a code example or explaining how it works?

Comment: Try removing the third parameter `callback` and then call your function.